# Zoho Deluge : how do i update table using large json file

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

New to deluge. My Current crm doesn't integrate with zoho so I'm having to update zoho manually using API calls.

So far I've used Deluge to get an access token and use said access token to get a large JSON file full of contact information.

Below, I've added 2 of many contacts in the JSON file. What I need is to take the JSON file I received in my response and

1. If the file exists update it (if it's changed).
2. If the file doesn't exist then add it.

**FILE SAMPLE**:

```
{  "TotalCount": 6787,
  "Data": [
    {
      "Location": {
        "Id": 9545707,
        "Name": "Primary"
      },
      "Customer": {
        "Inactive": false,
        "Id": 8873547,
        "Name": "John Ashley"
      },
      "FirstName": "John",
      "LastName": "Ashley",
      "PhoneNumber": "",
      "PhoneNumber2": "777777777",
      "Email": "email",
      "Title": "",
      "Fax": "",
      "Notes": "",
      "Id": 9342900,
      "Metadata": {
        "CreatedBy": "email",
        "CreatedOn": "2020-04-30T17:40:39",
        "UpdatedOn": "2020-04-30T17:40:39",
        "UpdatedBy": "email",
        "Version": 1
      },
      "ExternalSystemId": null
    },
    {
      "Location": {
        "Id": 9545829,
        "Name": "adress"
      },
      "Customer": {
        "Inactive": false,
        "Id": 8873674,
        "Name": "Ename"
      },
      "FirstName": "fname",
      "LastName": "lname",
      "PhoneNumber": "",
      "PhoneNumber2": "7777777",
      "Email": "email",
      "Title": "",
      "Fax": "",
      "Notes": "",
      "Id": 9343021,
      "Metadata": {
        "CreatedBy": "email",
        "CreatedOn": "2020-04-30T16:04:23",
        "UpdatedOn": "2020-04-30T16:04:23",
        "UpdatedBy": "email",
        "Version": 1
      },
      "ExternalSystemId": null
    },
    {
      "Location": {
        "Id": 9546128,
        "Name": "Primary"
      },
      "Customer": {
        "Inactive": false,
        "Id": 8873966,
        "Name": "name"
      },
      "FirstName": "fname",
      "LastName": "lname",
      "PhoneNumber": "",
      "PhoneNumber2": "7777777777",
      "Email": "email",
      "Title": "",
      "Fax": "",
      "Notes": "",
      "Id": 9343319,
      "Metadata": {
        "CreatedBy": "email",
        "CreatedOn": "2020-04-30T18:38:02",
        "UpdatedOn": "2020-04-30T18:38:02",
        "UpdatedBy": "email",
        "Version": 1
      },
      "ExternalSystemId": null
    }
  }
]
}
```

**Code I've written so far**

(this code doesn't work after the second "insert into contact table", on top of that it doesn't update — it just adds new lines)

```
jsonVar = getUrl("https://cloud.servicebridge.com/api/v1.1/Contacts?

pageSize=500&sessionKey=" + APIKEY);
DataVar = jsonVar.getJSON("Data");
DataList = DataVar.toJSONList();
LocationList = list();

for each  Locationdata in DataList {
    LocationList.add(Locationdata.getJson("Location"));
}

for each  Location in LocationList {
    Name = Location.getJSON("Name");
    Desi = Location.getJSON("Id");
    insert into contact_table
    [
        LocationName=Name
        Location_ID=Desi
        Added_User=zoho.loginuser
    ]
}

DataList = DataVar.toJSONList();
custList = list();
for each  custdata in DataList {
    custList.add(custdata.getJson("Customer"));
}

info custList;
for each  Customer in custList {
    Name = Customer.getJSON("Name");
    Desi = Customer.getJSON("Id");
    insert into contact_table
    [
        CustomerName=Name
        CustomerId=Desi
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it possible. Please optimize the code. Zoho can allow max 5000 lines in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `getUrl(url, null, false);`

This should return a Map

To clarify, is this function in the ZohoCRM?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Are you answering the post or asking for clarification?